# Тонкости реализации паттерна Builder

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Два вопроса по паттерну, сам не смог разобраться:

1. Почему внутренний класс `Builder` объявлен `public`?
2. Почему внутренний класс `Builder` объявлен `static`?

Comment: Для того, для чего нужны впринципе вложенные статические классы:  чтобы можно было позвать `Foo.Builder`.

Comment: @Nofate А есть еще причины, кроме вызова без создания объекта?  И обязан ли он быть public?

Comment: Нет, но это довольно весомая причина. Вообще никто не мешает вам вынести билдер в самостоятельный класс. Билдером он от этого быть не перестанет.

Comment: @Tariel, по-хорошему, вопросу не хватает кода той реализации, о которой вы говорите. Builder же можно реализовать существенно по-разному ;)

Comment: какой язык ? о чём вы тут речь ведёте, решительно не понятно? где пример кода?

Answer (score 0):

1. Модификатор доступа не связан непосредственно с архитектурой паттерна, а отражает стандартную политику доступа к объектам. Можно не объявлять.
2. Параметр static нужен для вызова класса без создания внешнего объекта, по типу Class.Builder().

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev  Вопрос основан на втором примере реализации паттерна на Java из вики.  Весь код там, нет смысла дублировать сюда.